# Thymeleaf View Resolver with SpringMVC webapp

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

How if one can use `ThymeleafViewResolver` as a defalt view resolver.

Currentely my `WebMvcConfig` looks like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.greatLearning.ticketAPI.controller")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

//    @Override
//    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//        configurer.enable();
//    }

    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }



    //Thymeleaf ViewResolver
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
        // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
        // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
        // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
        // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
        // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
        // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
        // for safer backwards compatibility.
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        // NOTE 'order' and 'viewNames' are optional
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".html", ".xhtml"});
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

for `*.jsp`  view it is  working just fine, but I want to use Thymeleaf to resolve my `.html` templates becasue I don't want to use  `*.jsp` .

One thing to note is that in my controller

`TestController.java`

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String method1() {
    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping("/hello2")
@ResponseBody
public String method2() {
    return "hello";  //This works fine
}
```

when I hit `/hello`  api this is what I get

[image: API Response]

How do I configre `viewResolver` so that spring picks up `ThymeleafViewResolver` to resolve `html` rather than `jsp`

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!!!!!
Here is what I did after an hour of debugging the libraries
in `WebMvcConfig.java` I revomed the `public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver()` method as it is sed to configure jsp.
Now in `ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver()` remove these two:
`viewResolver.setOrder(1);`
`viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".html", ".xhtml"});`
got help through debgging and [this post](Problem Solved!!!!!
Here is what I did after an hour of debugging the libraries
in `WebMvcConfig.java` I revomed the `public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver()` method as it is sed to configure jsp.
Now in `ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver()` remove these two:
`viewResolver.setOrder(1);`
`viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".html", ".xhtml"});`
got help through debgging and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222630/16439993).
As to why I will answer if anyone is interested. :)